# Start a foreground service from the background Android API 31

Tags: java, android, foreground-service

I have two voice recognition services. One is a wake-word service and the other is a speechRecognizer service. When the wake-word is recognized, the wake-word service has to be stopped and the speechRecognizer service has to be started. This works once, but when the wake-word service has to restart after the speechRecognizer service finishes, the following error appears in the logcat:

```
AppOps                  system_server                        E  Operation not started: uid=10382 pkg=com.example.andreabeta(null) op=RECORD_AUDIO
```

These are my permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICES_FROM_BACKGROUND"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

I've tried to turn off the battery saving for the application on the phone, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you find anything? I am facing the exact issue.

Comment: Facing the same issue using .NET Maui. It seems like both services are trying to use the microphone. As long as I dont dispose the KeywordRecognizer the SpeechRecognition can't use the microphone and the error gets thrown. I sadly still have no solution to this.